# Managing data charts

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, class-diagram

My dbml file is just getting bigger and bigger and more unwieldy:

[image]

I favoured an all-in-one approach as supposed to multiple data contexts because when I tried that it was near impossible to manage in code. I was advised it was better to have them all in one chart and the difficulty will be simply in managing this chart and not in code.

The chart I've got is becoming a pain to manage, if I want to even remove a table and re-add it it sometimes takes a little while to *manually* find it! There isn't even a list I can find in VS2010 of the objects you have in that chart!

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, group tables related to the same concept in the same diagram, and create multiple diagrams, yes that means you have to MANAGE each diagram; but generally this is a GOOD thing.  Here's why...  Same database schema, different diagrams.  Each diagram representing a specific subset of business.  So  product catalog section, an order section, a biling section, a returns section, a sales section.. etc.. Just make sure it groups up to a specific line of business.  Yes this does mean that tables will be repeated on different diagrams

By segmenting the table structure into business logic groupings, you can quickly see all related tables to that groping.  This is helpful to developers as they have to work in those specific sections; they understand the scope of work with out having to understand the entire database structure.  When making a change, if you find a table is on multiple groupings/diagrams you can see what areas of the business are impacted by the change.  This gives you an idea of the areas of the application which need to be tested and at a minimum considered when your making a change to the database structures.  Ideally this type of modeling would be implemented in relation to services offered in a Service Management style of architecture.  However starting to group your tables into business processes would help.  IF you think this is unwieldy... try looking at an oracle db that has over 1500 tables in its schema.

The overall trick here is to only show those tables/views related to the business process/service someone would NEED to look at to support the system.

Good luck!